# Use force:navigateToURL to open new window instead of new tab

Tags: javascript, url, javascript-controller

When I use force:navigateToURL, it opens the URL in a new tab.
Is there anyway to force this to open in a new browser window instead?

Thanks in advance, code pictured below

```
 var urlEvent = $A.get("e.force:navigateToURL");
 urlEvent.setParams({
            "url": "https://xxxxxx.pss.koresoftware.com/sfdc/ticketing/Activity/PhoneCallSave.aspx"
        });
 urlEvent.fire();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Browsers are free to choose if a new tab or window is opened, and can be configured by the user.

## Edit

You can, however, force a window by using window.open with the third parameter ("features"), but it will not be a "normal" window. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/726761) for more information.

Comment: Excellent Thank you!!